# DjangoRestFramework serializer does not recognize 'username' attribute even though it exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from CMSApp.mixins import SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin

from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class UserSerializer(SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
        custom_error_messages_for_validators = {
            'username': {
                UniqueValidator: _('This username is already taken. Please, try again'),
                RegexValidator: _('Invalid username')
            }
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            email = validated_data['email'],
            username = validated_data['username'],
            password = validated_data['password'],
        )
        return user
```

and this is my mixins.py:

```
class SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin:
    """
    Replaces built-in validator messages with messages, defined in Meta class. 
    This mixin should be inherited before the actual Serializer class in order to call __init__ method.

    Example of Meta class:

    >>> class Meta:
    >>>     model = User
    >>>     fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
    >>>     custom_error_messages_for_validators = {
    >>>         'username': {
    >>>             UniqueValidator: _('This username is already taken. Please, try again'),
    >>>             RegexValidator: _('Invalid username')
    >>>         }
    >>>     }
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # noinspection PyArgumentList
        super(SetCustomErrorMessagesMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.replace_validators_messages()

    def replace_validators_messages(self):
        for field_name, validators_lookup in self.custom_error_messages_for_validators.items():
            # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
            for validator in self.fields[field_name].validators:
                if type(validator) in validators_lookup:
                    validator.message = validators_lookup[type(validator)]

    @property
    def custom_error_messages_for_validators(self):
        meta = getattr(self, 'Meta', None)
        return getattr(meta, 'custom_error_messages_for_validators', {})
```

When I go to the URL /users/1, this is the view which is called:

```
class user_detail(APIView):
    """
    Get, update or delete a specific user.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
        if serialzier.is_valid():
            serializier.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

The issue is, when I go to the URL /users/1, Django returns an attribute error, saying:

```
AttributeError at /CMS/users/1
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'username'.
```

I checked my UserSerializer and I did specify correctly that

```
fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
```

so I can't seem to find the issue. Any idea why Django is giving an error saying that "The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance." even though 'username' is named correctly?

Comment: You may want to consider looking into the [generic views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). They handle most of what you are doing here automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `get_object` method, you're returning a 404 response instead of raising a `Http404` exception. Because of that, the `Response` is being passed into your serializer, and clearly the `Response` does not have a `username` field.

The last part of your stack trace said

> Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'username'.

Which was the signal: there is only one place where you are returning a `Response` back to a serializer.

Comment: ah, okay. So errors like 404 should always be raised and not returned, got it. But how come it is trying to get the 'username' attribute in the first place? Which part of my code is asking for the 'username' attribute?

Comment: In both `get` and `put` you are doing `user = self.get_object()`. Then you are passing `user` to your serializer, which is serializing the `username` field when you call `serializer.data`.